# Looking for Captcha field for webform

Tags: 7, webforms, captcha

I have tried: [Mollom module](https://www.drupal.org/project/mollom) and [Captcha module](https://www.drupal.org/project/captcha) to put a captcha in my webforms.

Had no problem at all -they work for non-admin users- but they don't fit all my needs because I need an actual field I can include in a form in a position I want (e.g. my webform has two columns and want to place that field inside of one of the columns, instead of adding it at the end). E.g.

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ First name              + Car Model              +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Last Name               + Car Color              +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ City                    + I need captcha         +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++ in this exact          +
+ Phone                   + line / cell            +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ T&C / ToU               +          Send          +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

But with those modules I get the captcha field as displayed:

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ First name              + Car Model              +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Last Name               + Car Color              +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ City                    +          Send          +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Phone                   +                        +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++                        +
+ T&C / ToU               +                        +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ I'm having the                                   +
+ captcha component at                             +
+ the end of the form                              +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

(which does not help since the "send" button is above the field and the field is not inside of any column).

What module could I install so I can create an explicit [web]form captcha field and place it where I want in the form layout?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe think about alternatives? We use [BOTCHA](https://www.drupal.org/project/botcha) module everywhere these days to combat spam submissions. Works much better than any captcha and is far less intrusive for real people. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a few ways to do this while still using the contrib catpcha or mollom modules.

First, you can use a hook_form_alter(), but you probably need to make sure that your module has a heavier weight than the captcha modules so that you can be sure to alter the form (and manipulate the `#weight` of the individual form elements) after all other modules have done their part.

A second, completely different way would be to [create a custom theme function](https://www.drupal.org/node/1092122) for this form.

I have done both approaches (depending on the needs of the project) and they both work.

As far as I am aware, there is no module that explicitly helps with the layout of captcha fields within a form.

Answer (score 0):

Use hook_form_alter and form api weight attribute of form element to handle this situation.